# Any tips dealing with GTFS-realtime v2 compared with GTFS-relatime v1

Tags: api, uses-of-open-data, public-transport, real-time

Transit Open Data APIs often use [GTFS-realtime](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime) for providing real time status updates (service late, currently here, effectively RT differences against scheduled services).

The [GTFS-realtime spec is now at v2](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/reference) for what seems like a lot of good reasons.

Wondering if anyone has any tips / advice / gotchas on migrating an existing code base (java) from v1 to v2?